# Encoding error passing JSON to PHP

Tags: php, json

A Dictionary is generated in Swift and converted to JSON to produce the following:

`{"recordId":"1184","category":"Audio","qtyInStock":"1","itemId":"54","itemName":"100.16.4 Snake","make":"LiveWire","plShared":"1","description":"100' 16-channel, 4-return audio","subcategory":"Snake","barcode":"54","showInResults":"1"}`

The JSON is then URL encoded and attached to a URL pointing at a PHP file. The encoded JSON is as follows:

```
%7B%22recordId%22:%221517%22,%22category%22:%22Audio%22,%22qtyInStock%22:%221%22,%22itemId%22:%221698%22,%22itemName%22:%22ADAPT-XLRM%22,%22make%22:%22StudioHub%22,%22plShared%22:%22%22,%22description%22:%22%22,%22subcategory%22:%22Adapter%22,%22barcode%22:%221698%22,%22showInResults%22:%22%22%7D
```

[According to this site](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/), that decodes back into the original JSON. However, when echoing that from the PHP file using the following code where `data` is the passed param:

```
$json = $_GET['data'];
echo $json;
```

The returned JSON looks like this:

```
{\"recordId\":\"1184\",\"category\":\"Audio\",\"qtyInStock\":\"1\",\"itemId\":\"54\",\"itemName\":\"100.16.4 Snake\",\"make\":\"LiveWire\",\"plShared\":\"1\",\"description\":\"100\' 16-channel, 4-return audio\",\"subcategory\":\"Snake\",\"barcode\":\"54\",\"showInResults\":\"1\"}
```

What is missing here that would generate this result?

Comment: You should disable PHP magic quotes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with -

```
echo stripslashes($json);
```

Comment: That has the same result.

Comment: 'stripslashes' was the fix!